# is_a? fails with single-table inheritance in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, single-table-inheritance

`Object#is_a?` is failing in the strangest way in Rails 3. I have single-table-inheritance set up as follows (simplified for brevity):

```
# resource.rb
class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  # blah blah
end

# video.rb
class Video < Resource
  # blah blah
end
```

In my controller, I have this:

```
def create
  @resource = Resource.find params[:resource_id]
  logger.info '@resource class: ' + @resource.class.name
  logger.info '@resource superclass: ' + @resource.class.superclass.name
  logger.info '@resource is_a?(Video): ' + @resource.is_a?(Video).inspect
  logger.info '@resource is_a?(Resource): ' + @resource.is_a?(Resource).inspect
  logger.info '@resource is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base): ' + @resource.is_a (ActiveRecord::Base).inspect
  # Do some other stuff
end
```

Invoking the `#create` action generates these log results:

```
@resource class: Video
@resource superclass: Resource
@resource is_a?(Video): true
@resource is_a?(Resource): false
@resource is_a?(ActiveRecord::Base): true
```

Note that the `Video` instance **is** an `ActiveRecord::Base`, yet it **is not** a `Resource`. This is not merely an academic concern. Framework code called from the action uses `is_a?` to check for a type mismatch, and it raises when it thinks the `Video` is not a `Resource`.

Yet in the Rails console, `is_a?(Resource)` returns true.

What in the world could be going on here?

Comment: I have noticed this same issue in rails 2.3.14 / ruby 1.8.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is apparently to restart the Rails server process. I don't know how this error crept in, but it did. And what's more, it has happened on multiple occasions on multiple computers.

So, to anyone else experiencing this problem, just restart your server. Whatever it is, it's ephemeral.

Comment: I just stumbled onto this problem, and the comment fixed it. Is this issue reported as a bug?

Comment: By the way, this happens because your parent model (Resource) is reloaded, but the model that inherits from it (Video) isn't.

Comment: This comment did not help with rails 2.3.14 and ruby 1.8.7.

Answer (score 0):

Does the record you found have `Video` in its `type` column?

Searching on the superclass collection will find subclass objects, and I guess that even though you explicitly searched the `Resource` collection, the actual object you found was a `Video`.

No idea what the discrepancy is in the Rails console though! Rails overrides `is_a?` for `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`, but in your case Rails shouldn't be munging any class names or anything...

Maybe did you use different ids in the console and in your controller?

Comment: Yes, it has Video in its type column. That's why it gets instantiated as a Video. But it seems to me that every Video should be a Resource--Rails or not, it's still Ruby inheritance. Video is a subclass of Resource, and is_a? looks at superclasses. And yes, I tried with the exact same IDs in the console and controller.

Comment: Also, I don't suppose it has anything to do with TimeWithZone, since that class's definition of is_a? wouldn't be used here.